# soundplayer.cs doesn't exist c#

Tags: c#, disassembly

I recently started out with C#, but I'm having trouble playing up a sound file with soundplayer function. This is just a simple calculator using if statements.  The error message i got was displaying in Disassembly+, which is something I've never experienced before. I'm using Visual studio community, and I'm on a mac if that's of any of help.

This is the error message I'm getting ;

> 00000000   ldarg.1
>
> 00000001   callvirt Object System.IAsyncResult:get_AsyncState ()
>
> 00000006   isinst System.Threading.ThreadStart
>
> 0000000b   ldarg.1
>
> 0000000c   callvirt Void System.Threading.ThreadStart:EndInvoke (IAsyncResult)
>
> 00000011   ret

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Media; 




namespace Calculator
{
    class MainClass

    {
        
          public static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            string start = "Weclome to the calculator ! Time to get some math done";
            string num;
            string add = "+";
            string sub = "-";
            string mul = "*";
            string div = "/";
            string sqrt = "v";
            string square = "^";
            string quit = "Quit";
            float Result;
            //Locates and loads the exit sound
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"/Users/MaxMalvin/Desktop/shutdown.waw");


            Console.WriteLine(start);

            bool shouldLoop = true; 
            while (shouldLoop)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose between +, -, *, / , v, ^ , Quit: ");
                num = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());



                try
                {
                    if (num == add)
                    {
                        float add1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number ");
                        add1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

                        float add2;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose another number ");
                        add2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());


                        Console.WriteLine(add1 + add2);

                    }
                    if (num == sub)
                    {
                        float sub1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number ");
                        sub1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

                        float sub2;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose another number ");
                        sub2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());


                        Console.WriteLine(sub1 - sub2);

                    }
                    if (num == mul)
                    {
                        float mul1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number ");
                        mul1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

                        float mul2;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose another number ");
                        mul2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());


                        Console.WriteLine(mul1 * mul2);
                    }
                    if (num == div)
                    {
                        float div1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number ");
                        div1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

                        float div2;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose another number ");
                        div2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());


                        Console.WriteLine(div1 / div2);
                    }
                    if (num == sqrt)
                    {
                        float sqrt1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number ");
                        sqrt1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());



                        Console.WriteLine(Math.Sqrt(sqrt1));

                    }
                    if (num == square)
                    {
                        float square1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number ");
                        square1 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

                        float square2;
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose how many times you want to raise exponentially ");

                        square2 = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

                        Result = (float)Math.Pow(square1, square2);

                        Console.WriteLine(Result);

                    }
                    if (num == quit)
                    {
                        //plays the exit sound
                        player.Play();

                        Console.WriteLine("Preparing for shutdown...");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

                        Console.WriteLine("Shutting off functions...");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                       
                        Console.WriteLine("Shutting down main system...");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);

                        break;


                    }
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    // Removes bug , app crashes when entering string value instead of float
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You state you are using Mac, just assume you are using .Net Core, it do not include `SoundPlayer` class [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0&term=soundplayer)

Comment: And forgot [this GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/74) may help you